# Passing ListView to hint

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make an edit feature for my todo list app. What I want to do is to tap an item on the list and then I would be sent to the new page where I can edit the item on my list. I am currently getting a warning :

```
This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint

Issue: Looks for text fields missing inputType or hint settings
Id: TextFields
```

I was wondering how can I pass the text in my `ListView` to my second activity as the first thing to be edited in my `EditText`?

This is what I have so far:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);
    etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
    lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);        // now we have access to ListView
    readItems();        // read items from file
    todoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);   //create adapter
    lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);        // populate listview using the adapter 
    setupListViewListener();
    setupEditItemListener();

}

private void launchEditItem() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, EditItemActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}


private void setupEditItemListener() {          // on click, run this function to display edit page
    lvItems.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchEditItem();
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: Use [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra) to pass the text to next activity

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from what you have posted what exactly you are trying to pass.  However, there are several things you can do.

(1) You can put a reference to your ListView in a subclass of Application.  Application is a good place to put application-scope global variables.

(2) Similar to (1), put a reference to the adapter in your Application subclass.

(3) You can pass the query or other list setup parameters to the edit activity and let it requery.

(4) You can pass the index or other key info from the selected list item using putExtra() to the intent.  You can pass updated info back to the main activity by passing back an intent.  The main activity will receive the returned intent if it uses StartActivityWithResult().